# Is java 8 vulnerable for VU#144389?

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2

There is a new vulnerability related to TLS implementations that may disclose side channel information via discrepancies between valid and invalid PKCS#1 padding.

https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/144389

I wonder if a java application that uses the default SunJSSE as a security provider is vulnerable.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

I found an Oracle feedback to this vulnerability claiming that Java is not vulnerable - https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/CHEU-AT5U75

Bottom line, if you are using a newer version than Java SE 7 Update 7 then your application isn't vulnerable.